# ODATA query doesn't work

Tags: json, odata

i want to query my challenge table to return all challenges that have one sponsor with id = xxxx

this is my json challenge`

```
`[
    {
        "id":"xuxu",
        "updatedBy":"System",
        "createdBy":"System",
        "sponsors":
            [
                {
                    "name":"Sponsor number 4",
                    "System",
                    "id":"53ED52E7-13A3-4AE0-8514-FAA3221C6F57",
                }
            ]
    },{
        "id":"lalala",
        "updatedBy":"System",
        "createdBy":"System",
        "sponsors":
            [
                {
                    "name":"Sponsor number 5",
                    "System",
                    "id":"YYYYY",
                }
            ]
    }
]
```

/challenge?$expand=sponsors&$filter=id eq 'xxxx'

i try this, but this wont work, can u fix this?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error or an unexpected result? OData is just a protocol, where is the *service* that exposes the data? Is any error logged there? Have you tried debugging the service?

Comment: unexpected result that what i get

Comment: So what *do* you get or don't get? Do you get any results, no results? Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Yes. First you should describe your actual payload and where is wrong. And take a second look, challenge should be a collection meaning the challenge should be plural. And for $filter in $expand, should be .../?$expand=sponsors($filter=id eq 'xxx')

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
GET /challenge?$expand=sponsors&$filter=sponsors/any(d:d/id eq 'xxxx')
```